# How to pass model settings to Session.Run() in C++?

Tags: huggingface-transformers, onnx, huggingface

In the Python implementation of ONNX, there is code like the following for PyTorch/HuggingFace models:

```
import numpy as np
import onnxruntime
from onnxruntime_extensions import get_library_path

audio_file = "audio.mp3"
model = "whisper-tiny-en-all-int8.onnx"
with open(audio_file, "rb") as f:
    audio = np.asarray(list(f.read()), dtype=np.uint8)

inputs = {
    "audio_stream": np.array([audio]),
    "max_length": np.array([30], dtype=np.int32),
    "min_length": np.array([1], dtype=np.int32),
    "num_beams": np.array([5], dtype=np.int32),
    "num_return_sequences": np.array([1], dtype=np.int32),
    "length_penalty": np.array([1.0], dtype=np.float32),
    "repetition_penalty": np.array([1.0], dtype=np.float32),
    "attention_mask": np.zeros((1, 80, 3000), dtype=np.int32),
}

options = onnxruntime.SessionOptions()
options.register_custom_ops_library(get_library_path())
session = onnxruntime.InferenceSession(model, options, providers=["CPUExecutionProvider"])
outputs = session.run(None, inputs)[0]
```

We are able to pass a dictionary `inputs` that provides information about how the model should be evaluated.

However, I'm not sure how to do this in C++. I checked [the `Run` API](https://onnxruntime.ai/docs/api/c/struct_ort_1_1detail_1_1_session_impl.html#af3f7d273f5e468ef21ef0d56d48c32fd) and I don't really see anything like this. How does one do this in C++? Do we have to define it through [`AddConfigEntry`](https://onnxruntime.ai/docs/api/c/struct_ort_1_1_run_options.html) in `RunOptions`?